# Selenium with Python - how to get it to fill out one textbox at a time

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Selenium with Python to login to a website, so it has to pass a username to one textbox and then password to another. When it's filling out the username, it *sometimes* starts typing the password in the same textbox (it doesn't usually type the full password in, only part of it). It's like it tries to type too fast and then starts typing the password before it selects the password textbox. How do I get it to enter text sequentially?

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=Config.driver_path)
driver.get(Config.start_url)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//someXPathToUsername').send_keys(Config.username)
driver.implicitly_wait(Config.driver_wait_time)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//someXPathToPassword').send_keys(Config.password)
driver.implicitly_wait(Config.driver_wait_time)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//someXPathToLoginButton').click()
```

Comment: Can you provide the (minimal amount of) HTML to reproduce this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set it so that it looks for the class or id of the div that you want to target [See more here about Selenium Locating Elements](http://#enters%20the%20email%20address%20in%20the%20username%20field) I think that is your problem, it doesn't know what to target and then it does it completely wrong.

look at the following code that I did

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import pprint as pp
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


def login(driv):
#insert the website url between the ('')
    driv.get('WebsiteURLHere')
 #select the username div by id
    login_email = driv.find_element_by_id_name('username')
#select the password div by id
    login_password = driv.find_element_by_id_name('password')
#enters the email address in the username field 
    login_email.send_keys('EmailAddressHere') 
#enters the password in the password field  
    login_password.send_keys('passwordhere') 
#finds the sumbit button and a click command to send info
    driv.find_element_by_id('btn__primary').click() 
    time.sleep(3)
    return (driv)
```